# Enable full float-capable snprintf() library with PlatformIO

Tags: string, float, platformio

I want to use snprintf() to format floats to a string.

I know the "normal" version of Arduino's avrlibc had all the float-formatting code removed to make it smaller.

I also know that at some point in the fairly recent past, it became possible to force gcc to use an alternate (forked?) larger Arduino avrlibc that had all the float-formatting functionality that was originally removed put back in.

However... I'm still trying to find an actual explanation of *how to **do** that* for an Arduino project using **PlatformIO**.

I found a clue someplace where someone said, "change linker rules in platform.txt file to enable floating point xxprintf()" (which hopefully enables floating point support in other float-to-string functions as well).

Problem #1: `platform.txt` appears to be global rather than local to this one project. There's no file named "platform.txt" anywhere in the project's directory.

Problem #2: I **do** have *several dozen* files on my computer named `platform.txt`... I don't know which one is the one that actually matters to PlatformIO, and I don't know enough about PlatformIO's internals to know how to figure out which `platform.txt` is the one that *matters*.

Problem #3: Even if I manage to figure out which `platform.txt` is the one I need to modify, I still don't know what exact modifications actually need to be *made*.

---

Update: I stumbled over a thread in Arduino's Issue discussion (["Sprintf for floats on Arduino Mega 293"](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/issues/293)) that said to append the text quoted further down to boards.txt. The relevant line appears to be `mega.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt`

So... I'm guessing that what I need to put somewhere in `platform.txt` (once I figure out which `platform.txt` is the one that matters) is `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt`

```
##############################################################

menu.printf=AVR printf Version
menu.scanf=AVR scanf Version

yun.menu.printf.default=Default printf
yun.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
yun.menu.printf.full=Full printf
yun.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
yun.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
yun.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

yun.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
yun.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
yun.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
yun.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
yun.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
yun.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

yun.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

uno.menu.printf.default=Default printf
uno.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
uno.menu.printf.full=Full printf
uno.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
uno.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
uno.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

uno.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
uno.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
uno.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
uno.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
uno.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
uno.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

uno.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

diecimila.menu.printf.default=Default printf
diecimila.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
diecimila.menu.printf.full=Full printf
diecimila.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
diecimila.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
diecimila.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

diecimila.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
diecimila.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
diecimila.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
diecimila.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
diecimila.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
diecimila.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

diecimila.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

nano.menu.printf.default=Default printf
nano.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
nano.menu.printf.full=Full printf
nano.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
nano.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
nano.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

nano.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
nano.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
nano.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
nano.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
nano.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
nano.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

nano.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

mega.menu.printf.default=Default printf
mega.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
mega.menu.printf.full=Full printf
mega.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
mega.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
mega.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

mega.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
mega.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
mega.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
mega.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
mega.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
mega.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

mega.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

megaADK.menu.printf.default=Default printf
megaADK.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
megaADK.menu.printf.full=Full printf
megaADK.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
megaADK.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
megaADK.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

megaADK.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
megaADK.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
megaADK.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
megaADK.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
megaADK.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
megaADK.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

megaADK.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

leonardo.menu.printf.default=Default printf
leonardo.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
leonardo.menu.printf.full=Full printf
leonardo.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
leonardo.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
leonardo.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

leonardo.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
leonardo.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
leonardo.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
leonardo.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
leonardo.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
leonardo.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

leonardo.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

micro.menu.printf.default=Default printf
micro.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
micro.menu.printf.full=Full printf
micro.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
micro.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
micro.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

micro.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
micro.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
micro.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
micro.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
micro.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
micro.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

micro.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

esplora.menu.printf.default=Default printf
esplora.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
esplora.menu.printf.full=Full printf
esplora.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
esplora.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
esplora.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

esplora.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
esplora.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
esplora.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
esplora.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
esplora.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
esplora.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

esplora.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

mini.menu.printf.default=Default printf
mini.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
mini.menu.printf.full=Full printf
mini.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
mini.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
mini.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

mini.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
mini.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
mini.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
mini.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
mini.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
mini.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

mini.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

ethernet.menu.printf.default=Default printf
ethernet.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
ethernet.menu.printf.full=Full printf
ethernet.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
ethernet.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
ethernet.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

ethernet.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
ethernet.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
ethernet.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
ethernet.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
ethernet.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
ethernet.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

ethernet.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

fio.menu.printf.default=Default printf
fio.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
fio.menu.printf.full=Full printf
fio.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
fio.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
fio.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

fio.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
fio.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
fio.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
fio.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
fio.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
fio.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

fio.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

bt.menu.printf.default=Default printf
bt.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
bt.menu.printf.full=Full printf
bt.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
bt.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
bt.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

bt.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
bt.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
bt.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
bt.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
bt.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
bt.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

bt.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

LilyPadUSB.menu.printf.default=Default printf
LilyPadUSB.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
LilyPadUSB.menu.printf.full=Full printf
LilyPadUSB.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
LilyPadUSB.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
LilyPadUSB.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

LilyPadUSB.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
LilyPadUSB.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
LilyPadUSB.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
LilyPadUSB.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
LilyPadUSB.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
LilyPadUSB.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

LilyPadUSB.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

lilypad.menu.printf.default=Default printf
lilypad.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
lilypad.menu.printf.full=Full printf
lilypad.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
lilypad.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
lilypad.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

lilypad.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
lilypad.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
lilypad.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
lilypad.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
lilypad.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
lilypad.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

lilypad.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

pro.menu.printf.default=Default printf
pro.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
pro.menu.printf.full=Full printf
pro.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
pro.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
pro.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

pro.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
pro.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
pro.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
pro.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
pro.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
pro.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

pro.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

atmegang.menu.printf.default=Default printf
atmegang.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
atmegang.menu.printf.full=Full printf
atmegang.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
atmegang.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
atmegang.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

atmegang.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
atmegang.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
atmegang.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
atmegang.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
atmegang.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
atmegang.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

atmegang.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

robotControl.menu.printf.default=Default printf
robotControl.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
robotControl.menu.printf.full=Full printf
robotControl.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
robotControl.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
robotControl.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

robotControl.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
robotControl.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
robotControl.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
robotControl.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
robotControl.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
robotControl.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

robotControl.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

robotMotor.menu.printf.default=Default printf
robotMotor.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
robotMotor.menu.printf.full=Full printf
robotMotor.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
robotMotor.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
robotMotor.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

robotMotor.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
robotMotor.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
robotMotor.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
robotMotor.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
robotMotor.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
robotMotor.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

robotMotor.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

gemma.menu.printf.default=Default printf
gemma.menu.printf.default.avr_printf_flags=
gemma.menu.printf.full=Full printf
gemma.menu.printf.full.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt
gemma.menu.printf.minimal=Minimal printf
gemma.menu.printf.minimal.avr_printf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

gemma.menu.scanf.default=Default scanf
gemma.menu.scanf.default.avr_scanf_flags=
gemma.menu.scanf.full=Full scanf
gemma.menu.scanf.full.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt
gemma.menu.scanf.minimal=Minimal scanf
gemma.menu.scanf.minimal.avr_scanf_flags=-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

gemma.compiler.c.elf.extra_flags={avr_printf_flags} {avr_scanf_flags}

##############################################################
```

#### Update 2:

I found what appears to be the solution & posted it as my own answer, but I'm going to hold off for a day or two to test it thoroughly and make sure it actually works.

Comment: For the record, both the “normal” and the “alternate” avr-libc are parts of the regular avr-libc. From the [documentation of `<stdio.h>`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html): “_In order to allow programmers a code size vs. functionality tradeoff, the function `vfprintf()` which is the heart of the printf family can be selected in different flavours using linker options._”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer at https://github.com/sstaub/LCDi2c

When using PlatformIO, add the following line to `platformio.ini` to enable full support for floats to printf():

`build_flags = -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm`

#### Caution:

This solution increases the amount of required flash by at least 2k. If you're using a Mega2560, you probably have flash to burn and really don't care. If you're using an Uno, Leonardo, Nano, or some other smaller AVR-based variant... it might matter, and you might *have* to care.

Tip: if the Nano/Leonardo/Uno doesn't have enough flash or SRAM, but you don't have space for a full-blown Mega2560, consider the "Arduino Nano Every". It uses the ATMega4809, with 48k flash and 6k SRAM.